# How to properly recover a Word2Vec model created using a SKLearn wrapper?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to create and store a gensin Word2Vec model using the *fit* function, then turn it into a SKLearn pipeline, pickle it, to later use it with *transform* on new data.

I created the wrapper, but the *self.w2v* object seems not to have been fitted and does not recognize any word. It is as if *self.w2v* had never seen *any* word.

Any ideas about how to address this?

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

class SentenceVectorizer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, vector_size=50):
        self.vector_size = vector_size
   
    def sent_vectorizer(self, sentence, vectorizer):
        '''
        Applies the fitted W2V model for each token of each sentence and returns their vector representation.
        '''

        sent_vec =[]
        numw = 0

        for word in sentence:
            try:
                if numw == 0:
                    sent_vec = vectorizer.wv[word]       
                else:
                    sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, vectorizer.wv[word])
                numw += 1

            except: # if word not present
                if numw == 0:
                    sent_vec = np.zeros(self.vector_size)
                else:
                    sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, np.zeros(self.vector_size))

        if numw > 0:
            return np.asarray(sent_vec) / numw
        else:
            return np.zeros(self.vector_size)

    def fit(self, X):
        self.w2v = Word2Vec(X, vector_size=self.vector_size)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_vec=[]
        for sentence in X:
            X_vec.append(self.sent_vectorizer(sentence, self.w2v))
        return X_vec
```

This code currently does well in training but returns zeroed vectors on inference (because no word has been recognized).

Most likely problem: fit method is not properly storing self.w2v, although when transform is called it seems to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had an outdated gensim version which required vectorizer[word] instead of vectorizer.wv[word]. I'll leave the question here as it might be usefull to someone.